# Iphone iterate over substring occurrences of a NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I would like to find all occurrences of a substring in a NSString, and iterate one by one to do some changes to that NSString. How should I do it?

Comment: Do you mean if you had `@"abcabcabcabcabcabc"` you want to iterate over all of the `@"abc"`s?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about

```
// find first occurrence of search string in source string
NSRange range = [sourceString rangeOfString:@"searchString"];
while(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    // build a new string with your changed values

    range = [sourceString rangeOfString:@"searchString" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(range.location + 1, [sourceString length] - range.location - 1)];
}
```

Or just

```
[sourceString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:searchString withString:targetString];
```

if you want to change the searchString to the same value everywhere in the source string.

Comment: Also using:

    NSArray *stringArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"mySubString"];

Comment: I tapped the wrong key and my answer was sent incomplete at first :-)

Comment: By componentsSeparated... you remove all the occurrences of your search string, you do not iterate over them ...

Answer (score 7):

I would go with something like this:

```
// Setup what you're searching and what you want to find
NSString *string = @"abcabcabcabc";
NSString *toFind = @"abc";

// Initialise the searching range to the whole string
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [string length]);
do {
    // Search for next occurrence
    NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:toFind options:0 range:searchRange];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        // If found, range contains the range of the current iteration

        // NOW DO SOMETHING WITH THE STRING / RANGE

        // Reset search range for next attempt to start after the current found range
        searchRange.location = range.location + range.length;
        searchRange.length = [string length] - searchRange.location;
    } else {
        // If we didn't find it, we have no more occurrences
        break;
    }
} while (1);
```

Comment: that's way to complicated, there's a method for that: `- (void)enumerateSubstringsInRange:(NSRange)range options:(NSStringEnumerationOptions)opts usingBlock:(void (^)(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop))block`.

Comment: Matt's method allows you to change the string, as it's not being enumerated, tho.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do changes, you could use:

`- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement`

but if that doesn't fit your needs try this:

`- (void)enumerateSubstringsInRange:(NSRange)range options:(NSStringEnumerationOptions)opts usingBlock:(void (^)(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop))block`

Comment: See documentation, as noted by HelmiB.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look on [NSString class Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

**Finding Characters and Substrings**

```
– rangeOfCharacterFromSet:
– rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:
– rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:range:
– rangeOfString:
– rangeOfString:options:
– rangeOfString:options:range:
– rangeOfString:options:range:locale:
– enumerateLinesUsingBlock:
– enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:
```

**Dividing Strings**

```
– componentsSeparatedByString:
– componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
– stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
– substringFromIndex:
– substringWithRange:
– substringToIndex:
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @TheEye's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9615941/659310), I cooked this up:

```
@interface NSString (EnumerateOccurancesOfString)

- (void)enumerateOccurancesOfString:(NSString *)string usingBlock:(void (^)(NSRange substringRange, BOOL *stop))block;

@end
```

-

```
@implementation NSString (EnumerateOccurancesOfString)

- (void)enumerateOccurancesOfString:(NSString *)string usingBlock:(void (^)(NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop))block {

    NSParameterAssert(block);

    NSRange range = [self localizedStandardRangeOfString:string];

    if (range.location == NSNotFound) return;


    // Iterate all occurances of 'string'
    while (range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        BOOL stop = NO;

        block(range, &stop);

        if (stop) {
            break;
        }

        // Continue the iteration
        NSRange nextRange = NSMakeRange(range.location + 1, self.length - range.location - 1);
        range = [self rangeOfString:string options:(NSStringCompareOptions)0 range:nextRange locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]; // Will this sometimes conflict with the initial range obtained with -localizedStandardRangeOfString:?
    }
}

@end
```