# Is the globe icon on keyboard a character or image?

Tags: ios, icons

I am building a keyboard extension for iOS 8 and wondering whether the globe icon is a character of some font or an image?

[image]

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f310/index.htm (by the way I found this by doing a google search for "globe unicode symbol" and clicking on the first result so party foul on you!)

Comment: @borrrden Thank you. If you copy and paste the 1F310 unicode character into Xcode Interface Builder, the font is in a blue color (not following Text Color attribute), which is different from the black color shown in above system keyboard.

Comment: That I can't help you with.  Does it also show blue at runtime?  Did you try changing the font?

Comment: Same problem here. Colour is blueish, independent for text colour setting. @ohho: did you find a solution?

Comment: Now the easiest way is to click on **Edit > Emoji**

Comment: @borrrden Do you mind posting this as an answer to be accepted?

Comment: iOS buttons use the tint color by default. All you have to do is set black as the tint color of your button and you're happy with the color.

Comment: Is it still the answer that OP wants?

Comment: @borrrden yes please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the character being used:  http://fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f310/index.htm (Unicode charpoint 1f310)

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there any way to get the character to render as plain text instead of its emoji equivalent? In both macOS and iOS it renders as an emoji and I can't get it to display in plain black as on the normal keyboard.

Comment: Emoji is basically "plain text" of the font that is being used.  You would need to use a font that has it rendered how you want.  I don't believe that an actual graphic is used, the vector emoji is literally what is in the font for that character.

Comment: Thanks borrrden. In the end I installed a different font and the emoji character (which is rendered as emoji in the source in Xcode) is rendered as plain text in that font. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522898/how-to-obtain-plain-globe-unicode-character