# Xcode: Position Images Inside UITextView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, uilabel, uitextview

I have a string that is added to the UITextView, and I would like to add images after a certain world in that string.

Example:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textview;    

textview.text = @"This is an icon of a cat. And this is an 
icon of a car. Here is more random text.";
```

This is an example of what I want:

[image]

How do I append and position images after a certain word?

I have an array that detects certain words:

```
NSArray *detectWords = @[@"cat", @"car"];
```

So I can detect when certain words show up in the text of a textview, but I'm not sure how to add an image right after those words.

Also, the string of words will vary in different situations (not static), so pre-positioning everything on the interface builder is not an option for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can either make a font with the images, and specify the correct glyph with an attributed string, or you can add `UIImageView`s, calculate the rects for the images and use Core Text to wrap the text around them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930462/ios-7-textkit-how-to-insert-images-inline-with-text look at this

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library it might help you

https://github.com/dzog/ImgGlyph

Answer (score 0):

Like this way, you can also do this,I hope it will help u
Here is how to put an image in the right portion of a UITextField:

```
 UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 500, 20)];
 textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;

 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];
 imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dog.png"];
 textField.rightView = imageView;
```