# Animated Gif inside UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930462/ios-7-textkit-how-to-insert-images-inline-with-text) question and it didn't work. I am also trying to avoid [this](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/ChatInMacOSX/blob/master/InMac%20Chat/NSAttributedString%2BMagic.m#L61#L78) sort of solution. In the end I am willing to go with a `CADisplayLink` and change each frame manually. Still, is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Do you just want an image in the `UITextView` or do you want the GIF to animate? If you're talking about `CADisplayLink` and frames then I assume you want it to animate?

Comment: I want the Gif to be inside the TextView and (hence being a Gif) to animate.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. Gif's don't have to animate, they can be just a single frame.

Comment: @vikingosegundo the problem is not animating a gif, it's actually viewing it animated inside a `UITextView` with `NSTextAttachment`.

Answer (score 4):

An animated gif if just a collection of images which are displayed in sequence at a timed interval. You can do this with a `UIImageView` like this:

```
imageView.animationImages = [UIImage(named: "uploadFrame0")!, UIImage(named: "uploadFrame1")!, UIImage(named: "uploadFrame2")!, UIImage(named: "uploadFrame3")!, UIImage(named: "uploadFrame4")!, UIImage(named: "uploadFrame5")!, UIImage(named: "uploadFrame6")!, UIImage(named: "uploadFrame7")!, UIImage(named: "uploadFrame8")!]
imageView.animationDuration = 1
imageView.startAnimating()
```

Then you can use exclusion paths to make the text flow around it.

Answer (score 1):

Use exclusion paths to define areas that are kept free, than add the image with an image view.

```
NSMutableArray *exclutionPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
[exclutionPaths addObject:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectInset(imageFrame, -4, 0)]];
[_textView.textContainer setExclusionPaths:exclutionPaths];
[_textView addSubview:imageView];
```