# How to insert NSAttributedString text and image GIF(auto play) to UItextview?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitextview

> I use NSAttributedString text ,and want attachment gif image to show  in UItextview

below mycode dostn't work for gif image

```
let mytext = UITextview()
let result = NSMutableAttributedString()
let attachment = NSTextAttachment() 
attachment.image = UIImage(named:"abc.gif")
let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment) 
let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"")
myString.appendAttributedString(attachmentString) 
result.appendAttributedString(myString)
mytext.attrbutedText = result
```

Please help to resolve Attachment gif image
And it will play automatically.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried to achieve that? Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how to ask a question in stackoverflow

Comment: Using stackoverflow First, please forgive the amateurish What could be wrong .

Comment: I want to make a play messages and Gif images automatically displayed in UITextview.

Comment: I had a look at <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135232/animated-gif-inside-uitextview>?  this question and it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Hi Please Try out this:

```
 UIImageView * imageview =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"download.gif"]];
 NSMutableArray *exclutionPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
[exclutionPaths addObject:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectInset(imageview.frame, -4, 0)]];
[_textView.textContainer setExclusionPaths:exclutionPaths];
[_textView addSubview:imageview]; 
_textView.text=@"Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...";
```

Comment: The image shows on the text and it 's not inline with the text .

Comment: To apply principles NSTextAttachment  can be inserted animate Image And static with Text inside UITextview

Iext + Gif +Text ..... static Image + text...blash.....

Comment: This same YYText  https://github.com/ibireme/YYText  ,
But I want to use UITextView 's swift provided .