# NSAttributedString with image doesn't work in UITextField?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, nsattributedstring, textkit

I'm inserting an image into an `NSAttributedString` with the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20930656

I've been able to get this working in a `UITextView`, but for some reason it doesn't work in a `UITextField`. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: how are you setting the text?

Comment: by using textfield.attributedText =

Comment: same problem here.