# NSLog displays the "treble clef" unicode, but the UILabel does not

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unicode

I'm trying to display the "treble clef" in a UILabel, but it doesn't work.  However, NSLog is able to display it.

```
NSString *strM = @"\U0001d11e";
NSLog(@"treble clef works: %@",strM); //works
NSLog(@"works: "); //works

UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
lbl.text = strM; //shows "empty" or (box around a question mark)
```

What am I missing to display that Unicode character in a `UILabel`?

Answer (score 1):

Since Xcode happens to use a font which has a glyph for the treble clef character, it shows up in the NSLog message.

However, the font that UILabel is using doesn't happen to contain a glyph for that particular Unicode character.  That's why you're seeing a "box around a question mark."

If you try a more common Unicode character, you'd see there is no problem with the code itself.

One option is to switch to a different font which supports that particular character.

If that isn't possible, you could try to [use an `NSAttributedString` with an inline image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20930462/4151918) of the treble clef.

Answer (score 0):

- Had to look into the Fonts that support Treble Clef as PetehChristian(gave him a point) said.
  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d11e/fontsupport.htm
  Liked Symbola:  http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/Symbola.zip
- Unzipped the file and dragged it to Xcode: Supporting Files.
  Bundled it into the target.
- Make sure in the BuildPhases:Copy Bundle Resources.
- Had to also put in the Info.plist: add(Fonts Provided by
  application). And add the file:  Symbola.ttf.
- Then verified the font was in the system:

  ```
  NSArray *fontFamilies = [UIFont familyNames];
  for (int i = 0; i < [fontFamilies count]; i++)
  {
      NSString *fontFamily = [fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i];
      NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:[fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i]];
      NSLog (@"%@: %@", fontFamily, fontNames);
  }
  ```
- subclassed UIView:(this is best for me anyway)

  [(NSString*) @"\U0001d11e" drawInRect:CGRectMake(50+10, 50-15, 80, 20) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:100]];
- To put out the unicode to label:(still issues here)

  ```
  [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Symbola.ttf" size: 40]];
  lbl.text = @"\U0001D11E";
  ```