# How to format numbers in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I realize there are a lot of questions like this already, but read on please, this one is most likely different.

So I have been working on a calculator app, and I would like the user to be able to press a button and be provided with the layout for a mathematical function (square, sqrt, log, etc.). This is a little hard to explain, so here is a screenshot of what I need, directly from Apple's grapher app:

[image: example]

See, the user can press one of these, and it will be inserted into the text field directly, and the user can then edit any attributes.

I would like to accomplish this while still being able to use a UITextField, so really, any suggestions or recommendations would be much appreciated, I just can't solve this.

Comment: What about adding an images overlay which is touchable for each element and calculating where to place it on the textfield, whilst storing the intended calculation?

Comment: You might have to look into UITextView and NSTextAttachment. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930462/ios-7-textkit-how-to-insert-images-inline-with-text might help

Comment: @NaveenRamanathan, maybe. That might be what I'm looking for, I will look more into it!